# How to remove the quotes when forming a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am creating a dynamic javascript object to query from the mongodb, and my code as follows,

```
 _.each(separatedFilter, function (str) {
        const filter = str.split('=');
        console.log('filter is', JSON.stringify(filter));
        if (filter[1] && filter[1].trim() !== '') {
            var key = `${filter[0]}`;
            var obj = {};
            obj[key] = filter[1];
            if (key = 'date.start:{$gte') {
                key = '"date.start":{"$gte"';
            }
            if (key = 'date.end:{$lt') {
                key = '"date.end":{"$lt"';
            }
            query.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

the above code creates a object as follows,

```
{ '$and':
   [ { name: [Object] },
     {},
     { '"date.start":{"$gte"': '2016-12-18T18:30:00.000Z',
       '"date.end":{"$lt"': '2016-12-18T18:30:00.000Z' }
     ] }
```

in the above object i could see  **`'`** at the start and end of date.start and date.end. whereas i just want it to be,

```
   { '$and':
       [ { name: [Object] },
         {},
         { "date.start":{"$gte": '2016-12-18T18:30:00.000Z',
           "date.end":{"$lt": '2016-12-18T18:30:00.000Z' }
     ] }
```

Comment: I think you are putting an extra quote here `key = '"date.start":{"$gte"'`

Comment: `How to remove the quotes when forming a javascript object?` stop putting them in

Comment: @JaromandaX can you post as answer

Comment: why? there's a perfectly cromulent answer already

Comment: i tried to remove '' , but that does not compile

Comment: @brk how to i solve it

Comment: @JaromandaX how can i solve please

Comment: Note.  = is assignment.  You want == in a comparison check

Comment: yes i changed that but still i see the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a value (the nested object) via a key, nor can you partially define an object with a key (i.e. `$gte`) but without a value.

A fix would look something like this:

```
if (key === 'date.start:{$gte') {
    obj['date.start'] = { '$gte' : null };
}
if (key === 'date.end:{$lt') {
    obj['date.start'] = { '$lt' : null };
}

obj[key] = filter[1];
```

This assumes that `null` will be replaced with the appropriate timestamps somewhere else in the program and then you can serialize that object to a string before sending the query.

### Explanation

These lines have a number of problems:

```
if (key = 'date.start:{$gte') {
    key = '"date.start":{"$gte"';
}
if (key = 'date.end:{$lt') {
    key = '"date.end":{"$lt"';
}
```

- They are inserting quotes into the key for some reason. Probably just a mistake.
- They are *assigning* to `key` *within* the conditional statement, rather than doing a comparison. This will have the effect of always executing the code within the `if` block, because the string being assigned and returned is always truthy.
- They come after the key and its value are already assigned to the object via `obj[key] = filter[1]`. Since the assignment has already run by the time the `if` statements do, they have no chance to affect the key that is used in the assignment.

Also, this line:

```
var key = `${filter[0]}`;
```

Can be simplified, as it is the same as:

```
var key = filter[0];
```

Or even better with `let` and destructuring:

```
let [key] = filter;
```

Comment: Updated again, as I think I spotted another problem. Note that my answer needs to be supplemented with whatever timestamp generating code you are using, as you did not include that in the question and it will be necessary to completely fix your problem.